# How to resolve 'No such entity.' error in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database

[image: 'No such entity.' error in magento2]

I am trying to setup the project in my local environment.I have changed the domain name in **core_config_data** table for path **web/unsecure/base_url** & **web/secure/base_url** and removed cache directory from **var** but still I am getting message `No such entity.` and errors attached at the screenshot. what is the way to resolve this?

Comment: have you remove your var folder from root and run command php bin/magento indexer:reindex and php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Yes I have run these commands

Comment: Hello @Ritika ,how you resolve this issue,I have same issue for multi website.Please help me.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. It appeared to be caused by some entity ids that needed to be set to 0.

When you transfer the data the insert records on these specific records are automatically generated and tend to start at 1 and not 0.

This script worked for me:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello @adam,I have same issue and applied your solution but not helping this code.

Comment: Is there any solutions for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **setup_module** table. Delete **Magento_Store** entry. Now setup upgrade should do the trick.

Remember, setup upgrade command does nothing when a module is up-to-date in the **setup_module** table. Hence when you delete the module from the **setup_module** table, setup upgrade will reinstall schema and data